# Where is "microsoft.portable.csharp.targets"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.4.5.

I have created a C# project using ILSpy and the "Save Code..." command.
It was created without any errors.

When I try to open this new project, VS displays the following error:

```
"The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Also, it was tried to find "Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" in the fallback search paths for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild". These search paths were defined in "C:\Users\MyUser\AppDAta\Local\TEmp\dev6AB3.tmp". Make sure that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct and that the file exists in one of these search path. C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\SomeProject.csproj".
```

I have searched for Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets on my C: drive, but it wasn't found.

How could I get this file?

Comment: Are you decompiling for a platform that is not installed e.g. .NET Core / Standard / UWP / ...?
Either install the platform or recreate the project.
Most *.targets are part of the MSBuild installer and some are extensions to MSBuild.
But it would be weird for the decompiler to rely on non standard *.target files.